# cannot be use as function, last line before return is error

Tags: c++, function, variables

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{

    int day, month;
    string season;

    cout << "Enter the month today: ";
    cin >> month;
    while (month < 0 || month > 12) {
        cout << "Enter valid month between 1 to 12: ";
        cin >> month;
    }
    cout << "Enter the day today: ";
    cin >> day;
    while (day < 0 || day > 30) {
        cout << "Enter valid day between 1 to 30: ";
        cin >> day;
    }

    string Months[{ "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December" };

    if (month >= 1 && month <= 3)
        season = "Winter";
    else if (month >= 4 && month <= 6)
        season = "Spring";
    else if (month >= 7 && month <= 9)
        season = "Summer";
    else if (month >= 10 && month <= 12)
        season = "Fall";

    if (month % 3 == 0 && day >= 21) {
        if (season == "Winter")
            season = "Spring";
        else if (season == "Spring")
            season = "Summer";
        else if (season == "Summer")
            season = "Fall";
        else
            season = "Winter";
    }
    cout << Months(month - 1) << day << " is " << season << " season! ";

    return 0;
}
```

The print in last line should be Month, day, season. The last line is error it says that the 'Months' cannot be used as function. What will I do to solve this? January 1  is winter season is the example of the outcome.

Comment: Array indexing uses square brackets i.e. `[]`, not round ones `()`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two syntactical issues in your code, one is in the definition of the `Months` array, it should be:

```
string Months[] = {"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
```

the other one is in the usage of `Months` as an array, for indexing you need square brackets:

```
cout << Months[month - 1] << ...
```

There might be other issues with the code but at least applying these fixes makes it compile. Good luck with your program.